# How to append two csv file with same column removing the duplicate rows in R

Tags: dataframe, duplicates, append, vlookup, rbind

I have two csv files `data_1` and `data_2`,

`data_1 - ID, Name, DOB, AGE, Income, ...etc` as column name

Both have 19 columns and 1000 row each.

I want to appended one after one to form a new data frame while removing the duplicate IDs  appearing data_2.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have done rbind(data_1,data_2)... but could not remove the duplicate values in ID.